# How to make mod_archive_odbc works on ejabberd 2.1.13?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mod-archive-odbc

I'm install ejabberd **2.1.13** from binary installer.
After module compilation and copying *.beam files to /*opt/ejabberd_2.1.13/lib/ejabberd_2.1.13/ebin* directory ejabberd crushes with this error (also with undef error):

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2014-08-25 16:45:07 ===
beam/beam_load.c(1365): Error loading module mod_archive_odbc:
use of opcode 153; this emulator supports only up to 152
```

Erlang OTP version is **R17**.
I've also tried to install **R15B1** on VM and compile module on it. After copying beam files i still see the same error.

What should i do to make it work?

UPD: I've tried to build mod on **R14B04** and get this error from compiler:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 26-Aug-2014::15:30:32 ===
beam/beam_load.c(1365): Error loading module gen_mod:
  use of opcode 153; this emulator supports only up to 152
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to checkout the repository from SVN (instead of GIT). Module compiles without errors (**on R14B04**). Server starts without error logs and warnings. Yep, it Works!